How does each team pull the opposite team with equal force in tug of war by Newton's third law?
How does each team pull the opposite team with equal force in tug of war by Newton's third law?
Is it even related to the third law? If a man A on right pulls the rope with 50N force, is it necessary that a man B on left also pulls with 50N force?

Yes, and the reason is that forces are the wrong way to consider the situation. Newtonian mechanics is one of the earliest sciences, and so it is unfortunate yet extremely likely for bad choices to entrench itself. If you think of what it is that the weaker person who is pulled to the point of flying off the ground is actually exchanging (other than energy) with the stronger person, you will realise that this Newton's 3rd Law is just saying something trivial.

Does this answer your question? Based on newtons third law


How does each team pull the opposite team with equal force in tug of war by Newton's third law?

This may seem counterintuitive, but if the teams are stationary then this must be true because if the tensions at opposite ends of the rope were unequal then there would be a non-zero net force on the rope and it would move in one direction or the other.

Is it even related to the third law ?

Sort of. Newton's Third Law tells us that if one team exerts a force $T$ on the rope then the rope exerts an equal and opposite force on the team. If the tensions at opposite ends of the rope are equal then the forces exerted by each team on the rope must also be equal.

If a man A on right pulls the rope with 50N force, is it necessary that a man B on left also pulls with 50N force?

No. Our argument above only applies to the total force exerted by each team - not to the forces exerted by individual team members.
Assuming a level playing field and considering each team as a single unit then the two horizontal forces acting on each team are the tension in the rope and friction from the ground. If team A manages to exert a force that is greater than the fiction between team B and the ground then team A will move backwards, team B will move forwards (assuming they do not let go of the rope) and team A has won.

If one replaces a section of the rope with a tension gage,
it will show the tension of that rope.   Why would that
not be the tension on the team A end as well as on the team B end?
There might be some slight effect if the rope has mass
and is accelerating, of course: that would imply a net force
difference between the tensions at the endpoints.

Newton's 3rd law tells that both tug-of-war teams feel the same force. It does not say anything about how the teams move because of this force.
That would be Newton's 2nd law. This one says that team A will move (accelerate) based on the total force exerted on team A. Not the force exerted by team A, but the force exerted on team A. Only. And team A only feels the force with which team B pulls. This force is not cancelled out (unless by friction).

It's not necessary that man B also pulls by 50N of force. It's just that if man B pulls with less of a force then he will be moved by the force exerted on him through the rope. If instead, he pulls with more of a force, he will be the one that will force man A to move.
Essentially, for everything to stay still, the total amount of force exerted on each object (man A, the rope, and man B) needs to be 0. For the net force to be 0, they need to be exerting equal force. If they stop exerting equal force, then acceleration will be caused as per Newton's second law; everyone will start moving.
This isn't so much a consequence of Newton's Third Law, as it is the consequence of Newton's Second Law, $ΣF = ma$, where $ΣF$ is the net force applied to an object. For the system to remain still, the net force needs to be 0, therefore the two forces applied on each object need to be opposite and equal (note that the Third Law speaks of forces applied on different objects, not the same object). The Third Law is not totally irrelevant here, as it helps us calculate how the forces are exchanged through the rope, but it does not lead us to any conclusions as to whether the forces applied by each side are equal or not.
This is why the game of tug-of-war works at all. If the forces were always equal, no one would ever be able to win. If they were always different, the game wouldn't last/give both sides a chance.
